# php - Cannot replace html entity using str_replace

Tags: php, html, replace, str-replace, html-entities

I have the following html entity codes:

`$html = "&lt;div id=&quot;sstssfb_aaa-theme_wrapper&quot; class=&quot;first_sstform_wrapper&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bscon sstform_wrapper&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;sst_formheaderbgr&quot;&gt;"`

I want to replace this string `sstssfb_aaa-theme_wrapper` with the new one using `str_replace` like so:

```
$num = 20;

$old = '#sstssfb_aaa-theme_wrapper';
$old = str_replace("#", "", $old);

$new = 'sstssfb_aaa-theme_wrapper' . $num;

$new_html = str_replace($old, $new, $html);
```

But it won't work at all and returning the original `$html` instead of the modified.

What would be the problem here and how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

It works after I trim the `$old` variable like this:

```
$old = trim(str_replace("#", "", $old));
```

Comment: please take a look at the last `str_replace` declaration...

Comment: Double quote the $html

Comment: agree with @SunilPachlangia because adding double quote on $html variable  should solve the problem

Comment: The replacement works as expected. Your original code was faulty, you corrected it in between. `$new_html` contains the replaced token.

Comment: I am sorry, the `$html` value was actually pulled from a form.

Comment: @arkascha is right, your code is working, don't see the issue.

Comment: not sure why it is still won't work in my environment. I done it inside wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$old = '#sstssfb_aaa-theme_wrapper';
$old = str_replace("#", "", $old);

$new = 'sstssfb_aaa-theme_wrapper' . $num;

$html = str_replace($old, $new, $html);
```

then printing the `$html` you will get the result.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate the difference to the OPs code?

Comment: After replacing need to assign it to the variable $html

Comment: Correct answer for the original code the OP posted, though the OP has changed the code in between.